# Replace zero in a matrix in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix

I started to read the famous "cracking the Coding Interview" book and I want to do the following exercice.

> Write an algorithm such that if an element in an MxN matrix is 0, its entire row and column is set to 0.

Here is the author's solution :

```
public static void setZeros(int[][] matrix) {
int[] row = new int[matrix.length];
int[] column = new int[matrix[0].length];
// Store the row and column index with value 0
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix[0].length;j++) {
        if (matrix[i][j] == 0) {
            row[i] = 1;
            column[j] = 1;
        }
    }
}

// Set arr[i][j] to 0 if either row i or column j has a 0
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; j++) {
        if ((row[i] == 1 || column[j] == 1)) {
             matrix[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
 }
}
```

I agree with the author about the main idea. We don't have to store the position of '0' in the matrix but only the position of the rows and columns that are concernerd. But what I found a little "strange" in her solution is that at the end, she did a loop on all the cells of the matrix, which is not necessary in my opinion.

Here is my solution :

```
static int[][] replaceMatrix(int[][] matrix){
  int M = matrix.length;
  int N = matrix[0].length;

  boolean[] row = new boolean[M] ;
  boolean[] column = new boolean[N];

  for (int i =0; i< M; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j<N; j++ ){
         if (matrix[i][j] == 0) {
            row[i] = true;
            column[j] = true;
         }
    }
  }

  for (int i =0; i<M; i++){
    if (row[i]){
        for (int k =0; k<N; k++){
            matrix[i][k]=0;
        }
    }
  }

  for (int j =0; j<N; j++){
    if (column[j]){
        for (int k =0; k<M; k++){
            matrix[k][j]=0;
        }
    }
  }
```

I'am newbie in programmation so I'm not totaly sure about this. But in my solution, **if we except the first step which is to store the 0 positions**, my second part of my programme have a time complexity of O(M+N) while her solution has a complexity of O(M*N).

The problem is that the general complexity will be the same O(M*N + (M+N)) is the same that having the complexity O(2*M*N), no? (I'm not totally sure).
For example, if it's a matrix with M=N, so the two complexity of the two programs will be O(M^2).

I really want to know if there is a difference or not about complexity in this case?

ps : I read that the space complexity can be improved with a bit vector. But I really didn't understand. Can you just give me a general idea about it (in Java)?

Comment: Feel free for any queries.

Comment: lets assume the matrix is 3x3, thats 9 iterations for the first loop, 9 for the second, so 18 in the original solution. now in your solution the first loop is the same so 9 iterations. then loop over all rows wich are 3, and set all colls which are also 3, thats 9 iterations. but then you need to do it again, for cols, so youd need 9 more iterations in another loop.

Comment: you could squeeze out a bit if you store the indexes of the affected rows. but in the worst case you still go over the whole array twice.

Comment: @yes yeah you're right. I made a mistake in my calculation. I have a complexity of O(M*N) not O(M+N). I was wrong about it. Because we execute the second loop AND the third loop (not or), so there is a multiplication not addition. Correct me please if i'm wrong. Thanks !

Comment: well in many cases your version offers less iterations. if youd only store indices it would be better in even more cases (fe. youd need to go over everything if only the very last element is NaN). but in the worst case all solutions are 2*M*N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is technically no difference in your and the author's solution because both of you have traversed the entire matrix.So both codes are same ** if we have to consider big O notation**

In fact the author's code is a little bit( *by little bit I do not mean a different time complexity*) **better**. Here is the reason:

Suppose in your boolean array of rows, all rows are set true. Then in your case you will go through all rows and through each element of every row which is basically traversing the entire matrix.

Suppose in your boolean array of columns, all columns are set true. Then in your case you will go through all columns and through each element of every column which is basically traversing the entire matrix.

So you will in effect **traverse the entire matrix twice.** But the time complexity of the codes is the same because O(M*N) and O(2*M*N) is same.

You have already done saving space, since you used boolean data type.

Comment: I understand now. I did a mistake in my calculations. I hought that I had a complexity of O(M+N), but it was O(2*M*N) (which O(M*N) in fact as you explain. thank you!

Comment: about the space complexity, the author said that "To make this somewhat more space efficient, we could use a bit vector instead of a
boolean array." It's that point that I didn't get well.

Comment: @salamanka44 A bit vector of length n will always take space of n bits but a boolean array of length n takes space that is machine dependent

Comment: @salamanka44 If you like my answer then you can upvote it too.

Answer (score 2):

Time complexity of your last two for loops is still O(M*N) as in worst case inner for loop will be running maximum value of k times.